# Adding a ChartPanel to JPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel, jfreechart

I've got some not working code here:

```
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(null, null, null, dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
    ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

    chartpanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
    jPanel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jPanel4.add(chartpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

So the problem is that the jPanel4 with a chart is not visible. When I add my chartpanel to a frame and make it visible, it works.

Anyone knows what's my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("asdf");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            series.add(i, Math.random());
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(null, null, null, dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
        ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartpanel.setDomainZoomable(true);

        JPanel jPanel4 = new JPanel();
        jPanel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel4.add(chartpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(jPanel4);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can you provide us with a bit more code? Do you put something else into `jPanel4`? There can not be more than one component in every spot (`NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST, CENTER`). Do you put your panel into a frame?

Comment: I don't put anything else in a jPanel4. I generate my jPanel4 from a gui because my Form consists of jPanel4, some images and some jTextFields, not only jPanel4. I was wondering, maybe the reason is that whole gui is automatically generated? I don't have JFrame. That's the whole code that matters.

Comment: You need to have a window to put your JPanel in, it can not just display itself. As you say you generate this JPanel from within a gui, I think there is already a JFrame. As you shouldn't work with multiple JFrames, I would recommend using a JDialog and put your panel in there, or put your jpanel somewhere in your already existing JFrame.

Comment: can you tell me how to add into frame or jpanel? because I put jpanel in my frame but could not display my map.. i don't generate from gui..manually puting panel for viewing.. but not able to show on that panel? :(

Comment: @Developer The last 7 lines put the `chartPanel` into a `JPanel` which is added to a `JFrame`. Isn't that exactly what you're asking? If it is not showing, your JPanel might not be displayed or so. Try putting a `JLabel` with some text in to see if that gets displayed. If not, something's wrong with your layout.

Answer (score 1):

do u have anything in `CENTER` Layout in jpanel else try adding chart in center

```
ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartpanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
jPanel4.add(chartpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

`NORTH` is actually top of the container.

Comment: @Doszi89 I have the same problem I want to add the graph to jPanel in my Gui without creating a  new Frame(); did you found the solution !?