# Adding Barchart in a chartpanel to a jpanel

Tags: java, jpanel, bar-chart, jfreechart, chartpanel

I've tried looking for answers to get this but it didn't work properly so here goes my question. I have created a barchart and I want to add this to a jpanel in a java swing application , here is my code for adding chart to the panel,

```
void addpanel(JFreeChart chart) {

ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
jPanel2.add(chartpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
chartpanel.setVisible(true);
this.add(jPanel2);
this.pack();
setContentPane(jPanel2);
jPanel2.setVisible(true);

}
```

but when I run this , chart is not visible in the jpanel2 and it don't give any errors.
How can I change this code to make it work ?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318488/adding-a-chartpanel-to-jpanel

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your program extends `JFrame` or [`ApplicationFrame`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/ApplicationFrame.html).

- A [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) *is* a `JPanel` , so you don't need `jPanel2` at all.
- The default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, and the default location is `BorderLayout.CENTER`.
- Call `pack()` *after* you add the contents to the frame.
- Call `setVisible()` *last*; you shouldn't have to call it for anything inside.

  ```
  void addPanel(JFreeChart chart) {
      ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
      this.add(chartPanel); //BorderLayout.CENTER
      this.pack();
      this.setVisible(true);
  }
  ```